# How to let multiple users run tensorflow programs using the same system at once?

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow, memory-management

I need to set up a system with the requirement that multiple users are going to be running their tensorflow programs on the same system. To test this, I am trying to run 2 instances of the same program. The first instance is running, but the second instance gives the `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error.

[image]

But I can see that the GPU is not being fully utilised. How do I fix this by allocating the memory better? Is there any built-in way in the tensorflow framework that would allow me to configure it in such a way that it can dynamically allocate RAM to instances/users depending on the number of programs running simultaneously? Or, if that's not possible, are there any schedulers that can schedule jobs to users in a serialized manner? Or, is there any way to let the unused space in the GPU to be used temporarily as the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there is any way to allocate the memory dynamically, but you can stop tensorflow from automatically allocating nearly all the memory of your GPU by setting gpu options for your session.

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=x)
```

It is often possible to reduce the allocated gpu memory quite a bit without any significant training time increase.

After fixing the memory this way you can use most common grid engines to schedule your jobs. The oracle one definitely works.